# Как сохранить позицию аудио файла? objective -C

Tags: ios, objective-c, аудио

Я хочу сохранить время остановки аудио и продолжить воспроизведение с места остановки после перезагрузки девайса. Как это можно сделать?

Я использую этот код, но у меня возникает ошибка.

```
CMTime targetTime = _audioPlayer.currentTime
[self.audioPlayer seekToTime:targetTime];
```

Ошибка:

Initializing ‘CMTime’ with an expression of incompatible type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double')

Как можно решить вопрос?

**UPD:**

AudioPlayer.m

```
- (void) song{
if (_index == 0) {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.mp3"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];

if (!fileExists) {
    NSString *stringURL = @"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6zMam2kAK39VHZ1cUZsM3BhQXM";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}

self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] error:nil];
}
else if (_index == 1) {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"2.mp3"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];

    if (!fileExists) {
        NSString *stringURL = @"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6zMam2kAK39R2Z5RlVWZkN3Vzg";
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }

    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] error:nil];
 }
else if (_index == 2) {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"3.mp3"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];

    if (!fileExists) {
        NSString *stringURL = @"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6zMam2kAK39a3JvWmZ6YTQ1NUk";
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }

    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] error:nil];
}
}
- (void)initPlayer:(NSString*) audioFile fileExtension:(NSString*)fileExtension
{

NSURL *audioFileLocationURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:audioFile withExtension:fileExtension];
NSError *error;
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileLocationURL error:&error];

if ([audioFile isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
    _index = 1;
}
else if ([audioFile isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
    _index = 2;
}

[self song];

}
- (void)playAudio {
[self.audioPlayer play];


}

- (void)pauseAudio {
[self.audioPlayer pause];

}
- (BOOL)isPlaying {
return [self.audioPlayer isPlaying];
}
-(NSString*)timeFormat:(float)value{

float minutes = floor(lroundf(value)/60);
float seconds = lroundf(value) - (minutes * 60);

int roundedSeconds = lroundf(seconds);
int roundedMinutes = lroundf(minutes);

NSString *time = [[NSString alloc]
                  initWithFormat:@"%d:%02d",
                  roundedMinutes, roundedSeconds];
return time;
}

- (void)setCurrentAudioTime:(float)value {
[self.audioPlayer setCurrentTime:value];
}
- (NSTimeInterval)getCurrentAudioTime {
return [self.audioPlayer currentTime];
}
- (float)getAudioDuration {
return [self.audioPlayer duration];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В AVPlayer это:

```
CMTime targetTime = _player.currentTime//запомнить текущее время
[_player seekToTime:targetTime];//переход
```

**UPD:**

Для AVAudioPlayer это:

```
NSTimeInterval targetInterval;
targetInterval = [_audioPlayer currentTime];
[_audioPlayer setCurrentTime:targetInterval];
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос, не могли бы во помочь?

Comment: @User обновил ответ, в AVAudioPlayer метод работает немного по другому, currentTime возвращает тип NSTimeInterval. Добавьте ваш код и уточните в каком месте у вас проблема.

Comment: Добавил код AudioPlayer.m до применения вашего кода. Ничего не происходит, когда добавляю его.